# Best practice to save video from ipcam with cv2.Writevideo for 10 seconds?

Tags: python, async-await, sleep, opencv

Some problems here when i record the video like above. Any sugestion?

What i want:
When button clicked it should access ipcam, and save a 10 second video to a file.

```
    def get_image(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://' + self.usr + ':' + self.pwd + '@' + self.url)

        if not cap.isOpened():
            return False

        frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
        frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

        out = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('chatbot/ccam/records','fdoor.avi'), cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))

        t_end = time.time() + 10
        while time.time() < t_end:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                out.write(frame)

        cap.release()
        out.release()

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        return True
```

Some errors appears sometimes, without explanation:
[image]

Comment: What happens when this code is executed?

Comment: Hello Jamie, simply make file substitution with short videos, 2/3seconds

Comment: I didn't encounter any problem when running your code. It successfully copied part of a video file. What errors are you getting?

Comment: You get a 10 second video all the time u run the code?

Comment: I run my code outside my main program and it runs well :o